# Flutter: App gets stuck at loading screen

Tags: flutter

It works well on an Android emulator. But when I build the apk file and run it on my android device, it just gets stuck at the loading screen. Feel free to clone the repo.

Here is the link to the project I have uploaded
https://github.com/umakanth-pendyala/covid_19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not add [Internet permission](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting) to your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Goto `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` just before the `<application`