# problem with online images in apk (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, apk

I'm new here and just started learning dart a week ago. 
I am building a project and I'm using Image.Network(url) to show the images because I'm gonna need to communicate with a database later on the project.
all the photos in the app are from the internet... and when I'm building the apk file to my phone, the photos just won't show up. It obviously has a problem with the communication with the internet.. but idk what it is..
[Here's the app photo (ignore the language pls..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hkaT.png)

Here's the source code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Container myHomework(
      String heading, String subHeading, String hwCategoryEmoji) {
    return Container(
        width: 150,
        child: Card(
          color: Color(0xFF3D3D3D),
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Container(
                  height: 25,
                  width: 25,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/123.png"),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  heading,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      fontSize: 13,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  subHeading,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 11),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  final String personName = "ליאם רחום";
  final String personImage =
      "https://instagram.ftlv6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/p1080x1080/100909907_261706925023177_4991314082934193948_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.ftlv6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=101&_nc_ohc=qvNVUzKyb04AX-jlrb_&oh=55c9b8538d7c55375e5cf9d976d64c4c&oe=5F15CB42";
  final String currentCourse = "פייתון - מתקדמים";
  final String currentCourseImage =
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1461749280684-dccba630e2f6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80";
  final String popularCourseImage =
      "https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/liquicity-digital-art_62312_1920x1080.jpg";
  final String popularCourseTitle = "למדו אומנות דיגיטלית\n עכשיו בשידור חי!";
  final String hw = "מתמטיקה";
  final String hwCategory = "נושא - אלגברה";
  final String hwCategoryPicture =
      "https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/926/800/33/math-wallpaper-preview.jpg";
  final String hwCategoryEmoji = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1C1D21),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SafeArea(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 62,
                        width: 62,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 90,
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(0, -0.85),
                  child: Flexible(
                    child: Text("שלום, $personName!",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            fontSize: 16)),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 62,
                      width: 62,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xFF3D3D3D),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 62,
                        height: 62,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(personImage),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                spreadRadius: -8,
                                blurRadius: 13,
                                offset: Offset(3, 3))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 80,
                        width: 300,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                colors: [
                                  Color(0xFFFF2424),
                                  Color(0xFF8630F6)
                                ])),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: Container(
                                  width: 75.0,
                                  height: 55.0,
                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                      image: new DecorationImage(
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        image: NetworkImage(currentCourseImage),
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                            ),
                            Flexible(
                              child: ListView(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment(0, -0.7),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            ":קורס נוכחי",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                                fontSize: 17,
                                                decoration:
                                                    TextDecoration.underline),
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                  ),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment(-3, 0),
                                    child: Flexible(
                                      child: Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment(.44, 0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          currentCourse,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                            fontSize: 17,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: Text(
                      "פופולארי בקרב תלמידים",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 300.0,
                      height: 85.0,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: NetworkImage(popularCourseImage),
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(0, -0.5),
                        child: Text(
                          popularCourseTitle,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              shadows: [
                                Shadow(
                                  color: Color(0xFF000000),
                                  offset: Offset(-1, 1),
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                )
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: Text("משימות לעשות",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            fontSize: 16)),
                  )),
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      height: 100,
                      child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          myHomework(hw, hwCategory, hwCategoryEmoji),
                          myHomework(hw, "נושא - גיאומטריה", hwCategoryEmoji),
                          myHomework(hw, hwCategory, hwCategoryEmoji),
                        ],
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                              heroTag: "profileBtn",
                              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                              label: Text(
                                "פרופיל",
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ProfilePage()),
                                );
                              })),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      ),
                      Align(
                          child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                              splashColor: Color(0xFFFF1170),
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFF1170),
                              heroTag: "searchBtn",
                              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                              label: Text("חיפוש",
                                  style:
                                      TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => SearchPage()),
                                );
                              })),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: could you be more precise in wht you need

Comment: all the photos in the app are from the internet... and when I'm building the apk file to my phone, the photos just won't show up.
It obviously has a problem with the communication with the internet..
but idk what it is..

Comment: Is the database you are using online? and are the data from the API loading successfully?

Comment: I'm not using a database right now, just images from URLs but my phone can't communicate with them..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62261831/10835183
That should help you

Comment: Well, now I have another problem with the code... (Sorry to bother yall),
Now when I run the APK app it shows me half grey half black screen (it's not related to the network permission), does anybody knows what it is?

Answer (score 0):

As Flutter has its manage internet permissions itself, I don't think its the due to Permissions.

I would suggest you use `Image.network` instead of `NetworkImage(),`