# Problem with accessing the Web using Flutter (REST API)

Tags: flutter

My app works normally on the device if I'm connected via cable (debug mode), but it doesn't work if I compile the app and install it on the device. The images do not appear and I cannot connect to the database.

Commands:
flutter build apk
flutter install

I use:
const SERVER_NAME = "mydomain.com/api";

Is this a problem with permission?

Debug mode:

[image]

Installed:

[image]

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62261831/10835183

Comment: Yes... My manifest: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mysongs_v2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
</manifest>

Comment: that looks like your `debug` manifest. The answer talks about your `main` manifest

Comment: Thank you very much ... the problem has been solved. I didn't know that there are two files. :)

Comment: You can always upvote that answer if it helped you

Comment: Of course I want to upvote. I already did it :)