# API does not work in "flutter run --release" mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to make an application to query CEPs through an API, in debug mode it works perfectly and returns the results, but running the command "flutter run --release" it does not return the results. I've searched in many forums but I found almost no explanation about this error (sorry English, I'm Brazilian)

EDIT: Thanks for the answers, I managed to resolve the following error: `"<android usage permission: name =" android.permission.INTERNET "/>"` to the file AndroidManifest.xml

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Linux, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /home/vitor/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (3 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /home/vitor/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: /home/vitor/Downloads/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /home/vitor/Downloads/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • LM X210 • LMX21083ab400e • android-arm • Android 7.1.2 (API 25)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261690/flutter-app-gets-stuck-at-loading-screen/62261831#62261831 Does this answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: App gets stuck at loading screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261690/flutter-app-gets-stuck-at-loading-screen)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to build an apk using `flutter build apk` command and run it on your device.

This may work because I've faced this same problem before.

It was not working properly in `flutter run --release` but worked when i build the apk.